# Getting "No command 'pew' found" every time I open the Terminal (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The problem is when I open up a Terminal, I get this message.

```
No command 'pew' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pyew' from package 'pyew' (universe)
 Command 'new' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 Command 'pen' from package 'pen' (universe)
 Command 'pex' from package 'pex' (universe)
 Command 'pmw' from package 'pmw' (universe)
 Command 'peg' from package 'peg' (universe)
 Command 'paw' from package 'paw-common' (universe)
 Command 'spew' from package 'spew' (universe)
 Command 'pev' from package 'pev' (universe)
 Command 'pee' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
 Command 'psw' from package 'wise' (universe)
pew: command not found
bash: : No such file or directory
ubuntu@ubuntupc:~$
```

I got this message while I was trying to install and run this [CVPR project](https://github.com/jmfacil/camconvs).

What I did was

> 1. made a virtual environment `ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 cvpr_env`
> 2. activated virtual environment `ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master$ source cvpr_env/bin/activate`
> 3. installed project requirements `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master$ pip install -r
>      requirements.txt`
> 4. installed cmake-setuptools `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master$ pip install
>      cmake-setuptools`
> 5. installed pew `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master$ pip install pew`
> 6. did these `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master$ cd lmbspecialops`
> 7. `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master/lmbspecialops$ python setup.py install`
> 8. `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master/lmbspecialops$ pew add python`
> 9. `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master/lmbspecialops$ cd ..`
> 10. `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master$ export LMBSPECIALOPS_LIB="/path/to/camconvs/lmbspecialops/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lmbspecialops.so"`
> 11. `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master$ pew add python/`

After doing these, the message showed up every time while opening a new terminal and rebooting the system did not fix this issue.

I am new to Ubuntu and I don't know what I have done to the system. Question is, how do I stop these messages showing up?

**UPDATE 2**

My ~/profile is this? Sorry, I am not sure.

```
ubuntu@ubuntupc:/etc$ sudo cat profile
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

I also checked profile.d folder and I cannot see any pew related ones.

```
ubuntu@ubuntupc:/etc$ ls profile.d
appmenu-qt5.sh    bash_completion.sh     vte-2.91.sh
apps-bin-path.sh  cedilla-portuguese.sh
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, opening a terminal runs the contents of the `~/.bashrc` file. There is probably something in there that calls `pew`, and unfortunately, since you installed `pew` while you were inside a virtualenv (`cvpr_env`), `pew` got installed in the virtualenv directory (ex. `cvpr_env/bin/pew`) instead of the standard /usr/bin/pew. Check your `~/.bashrc` or re-install pew but *outside* of a virtual env.

Comment: @GinoMempin YES! I've found pew related lines at ~/.bashrc, and after deleting them no more messages! Thank you!

Comment: Great. But while that might have worked, I think if the CVPR project is dependent on `pew`, you need to install and use it properly. I don't know why that project adds `pew` lines to your .bashrc, but check [my more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60392181/2745495) on how to get it to work inside `bashrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60294493/2745495), the cause of the problem is this:

> 5. installed pew `(cvpr_env) ubuntu@ubuntupc:~/Downloads/camconvs-master$ pip install pew`

Here you installed `pew` while you were inside a `virtualenv`.

As mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293300/something-runs-automatically-while-opening-a-terminal-ubuntu-16-04#comment106802954_60293300), installing `pew` installs a binary under one of the *standard* `bin` folders, which is usually `/usr/local/bin/` or `/home/<username>/.local/bin` or `/usr/bin`, depending on your Python/`pip` installation permissions.

```
gino:~$ python3 -m pip install --user pew
Requirement already satisfied: pew in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv>=1.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pew) (16.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=17.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pew) (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pew) (0.5.3)

gino:~$ which pew
/home/gino/.local/bin/pew
```

Notice I said *standard* folders, because on Ubuntu, those folder paths are, by default, included in the `PATH` environment variable. Try it with `echo $PATH`. This is a list of all the paths where the system finds an executable. So that when I enter just `pew` (without the full path), the system knows where to find it. If it can't, it throws that error you get: "*No command 'pew' found*".

Now, going back to what you did, because you installed `pew` while inside a virtual environment `(cvpr_env)`, `pew` would then be installed in that virtual environment's `bin` folder:

```
gino:~$ upvenv cvpr_env
(cvpr_env) gino:~$ pip install pew
...
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3 distlib-0.3.0 filelock-3.0.12 importlib-metadata-1.5.0 pew-1.2.0 six-1.14.0 virtualenv-20.0.5 virtualenv-clone-0.5.3 zipp-3.0.0

(cvpr_env) gino:~$ which pew
/home/gino/.venvs/cvpr_env/bin/pew
```

.. and that path to the virtual environment directory isn't part of the *standard* paths listed in `PATH`. You can add an `echo $PATH` line in your `.bashrc` before the `pew` lines to print all the paths.

So what to do? 
Here are the possible solutions:

1. Install `pew` **outside** of a virtual environment

   - IMHO, this is the simplest.
   - From the [pew](https://github.com/berdario/pew/blob/master/README.md) docs, it is *supposed* to be a wrapper for the Python virtual environment. So you use it to activate and work inside a virtual env. You don't need to manually do `virtualenv activate` to use `cvpr_env`. Check the [common workflow](https://github.com/berdario/pew/blob/master/README.md#common-workflow) for usage.
   - From the [canconvs](https://github.com/jmfacil/camconvs#use-instructions) instructions, it says to use `pew` as your virtual environment.
2. If you are already have your own virtual environment, then there is no need to install and use `pew`. But if you *really* want to have `pew` inside of a virtual environment (not sure how this is going to work), you can do one of the following:

   - Add the `/path/to/venv/bin/pew` to your `PATH` environment variable. In `.bashrc`, add these **before** the lines that call `pew` (use `which pew` inside your virtual env to get the correct path)

     ```
     export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/your/venv/bin/pew"
     ```
   - Specify the full path to `pew` in `.bashrc`

     ```
     /path/to/your/venv/bin/pew ...
     ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me what you did here is you installed `pew` while within your virtual environment (`cvpr_env`) instead of on your host system. When you open a new terminal it runs through and executes the commands in your `~/.profile`, so my guess is that `pew` perhaps edited that file? Is there anything in there that's `pew`-related?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but sadly I cannot find any pew related ones. Maybe I am not finding properly?